# Redirect if no JavaScript

Tags: php, apache, redirect, noscript

Here's my situation:

I'm trying to redirect users with JavaScript disabled to a PHP generated page (instead of an AJAX generated page) on my Apache server.

I'm currently using:

`<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://mydomain/no_js.php">
</noscript>`

Is there a way to redirect users BEFORE the page loads?

P.S.: If not then any way faster than the one I'm currently using?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't detect whether javascript is enabled until you check for it, which requires the page to load, at least up to the noscript tag.

Comment: Not if you need to detect JavaScript. Put that `<noscript>` tag higher up on the page. Ideally before all `<script>` and `<link>` tags

Comment: window.locatio....  oh wait >:)

Comment: Just my 2 cents, but don't bother *optimizing* for users without js. It's ok if the page loads a little.

Comment: Additionally, just do the first cold load without AJAX. It would be the same thing, ajax is normally used to prevent page reloads but of course you can't prevent the first one. Check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement

Comment: Nice Wiki Entry, and I wanted to optimize for people using older mobile browser and the PS3 browser (Yeah I know it's not THAT common) where a simple redirect takes AGES... Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: @PhilippeTrépanier: Next time you have a question, add any relevant context (like the bit you just mentioned). I'm not sure how it would have affected your replies in this case, but it always helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to redirect, make the PHP version the default and redirect if javascript is enabled.  I would avoid this though and not have a redirect at all and just display on the same page based on whether javascript is enabled/disabled. You can show the javascript items if enabled.  I usually have a class name no-script in the body of the page and remove it if javascript is enabled, you can then use CSS to target what to display based on that one tag.

Comment: Actually this is not the best option at all. The vast majority of users will have JavaScript enabled. Optimize for the majority. Not for the very, very small minority.

Comment: I reworded it. I don't recommend redirecting, I just meant if they have to do it that way, I would reverse it.

Comment: That actually makes alot of sense. Only thing is that I would have to use CSS classes on every element that differs (not that many although). Best answer yet!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is going to do what youre looking for but here goes:

1. First, create a page that checks to see wether or not javascript is active
2. Second, if javascript is active, redirect to the correct page
3. If not, redirect to the page created for when its not active

that way the page that you have without js enabled never lads without js bwing enabled. not in the slightest. If you **REALLY** need scripts just holler...

Comment: I still would have to redirect + this increase load bandwidth usage (the landing page). I don't think it's more efficient than the way I'm currently doing it.

Comment: But realistically, this is the only way to direct before the page loads, as asked. just answering the question ;)

Comment: +1 for proving me wrong LOL

Comment: @PhilippeTrépanier OR and mind you i gaurentee this is not the correct or best way to do this, and i DO NOT recomend it, you could simply put the no javascript page inside of the `<noscript>` tag and then put a php die function at the end of the tag. If you do go that route, let me know how if fares for you ....

Comment: I did think about that but I figured out it wasn't the best way to do it.

Comment: @PhilippeTrépanier Hey jsut stumbled upon this, felt like it belonged here :) http://laucheukhim.github.com/instano/

Comment: Wow ill definitely look into this thanks :D