# noscript tag in a script tag?

Tags: javascript, noscript, script-tag

Is it possible to put a noscript tag in a script tag ?
Because I would like to perform a function that will check if JS is enable and if not it will redirect to an other link like this :

```
<script>
window.setInterval(function(){

   <noscript>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://192.168.1.1/index.html" />
   </noscript>

}, 5000);
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: You've to rethink the logic. You can't put HTML tags in a script, nor the interval will be never executed, if JS is not enabled.

Comment: What is the point of the setInterval in this? why not just use the noscript tag?

Comment: No, Anything inside the script tag will be parsed as javascript.

Comment: No, you can't. Whatever comes inside script tag is treated as js code instead of html.
say, how is your code supposed to work in js enabled browser?

Comment: Only when you're high! /s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Aside from being unable to put markup inside a script in the first place, it wouldn't make any sense.

The script can't partially execute then discover that JavaScript is turned off entirely.

Answer (score 2):

As other people mentionted, it is impossible and senseless.

If you want to redirect a user to another page after 5 seconds, if JavaScript is disabled, then add this HTML to your `head` tag:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <noscript>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://www.sadtrombone.com/" />
    </noscript>

  </head>
</html>
```

`5` in the beginning of this meta `content` stands for 5 seconds.

**Important note:** According to [XHTML Strict DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd), `<noscript>` tag is disallowed in `head` section. By using this code you make your **HTML non-valid**. However, it works on most browsers.

So, it is a good idea to avoid this. You can simply make a "Your browser is not supported" page with a link.

Good SO questions:
[Redirect if no JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988290/redirect-if-no-javascript)
[No-Javascript Detection Script + Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895012/no-javascript-detection-script-redirect)

Comment: Yes, I already try this and it works. But my aim is to check if the user disabled JS after he loads the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is incorrect.
If you want to check `js` you just need to use  `<noscript>`.
Inside script its not making any sense.

**Edited:**

What you are looking for is to check if user block `js` after page loaded.

Ans:No you can't.

There is no way to check if user block js after your page loaded.

Comment: The issue is if the user block JS after he loads the page, I would like to redirect him to an other page. That's why I though about making a function that will check every 5 seconds if JS is enabled

Comment: No there is no way to check  `js` after page is loaded.You can refresh your page with some interval .

Comment: edited my answer after understanding your requirement.